# How can i read data from an excel file to flutter

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, firebase-storage

I am trying to make an app with 4 user types and the file will have phone numbers and user type because i wanted to let people sign in if their phone numbers are on the list and get their user types too and the list can be an excel or spread sheet and the file will be saved on firebase cloud storage.

Comment: if you just want to save list of users with phone number and user type on firebase cloud storage you can make collection of users on Firebase also and than just with query and get request check if there is user with desired credentials.

Comment: How do i do that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use Firebase collections.

That is Non-SQL database. That is like you have one folder let's name it "users" and in that folder you have a lot of documents. These documents are like arrays of json objects. One of these documents would have properties like these (id, phoneNumber, userType).

Here is example of CRUD(Create, Read, Update, Delete) with Firebase and collections: https://medium.com/@atul.sharma_94062/how-to-use-cloud-firestore-with-flutter-e6f9e8821b27 .

This example is based on books collection, you can use this for reference and design your user model on this example.

Comment: I know i cn do it that way but it will take a lot of time to add every phone number and type for every single user

Comment: @Tripping you have convertor for excel to json, you get result in json and just do import with application.

Comment: Thankyou very much i will try it i will let you know i had a buzzy day sorry

Comment: thank you allot your answer acctually gave me allot of ideas to. use thank you for your help sorry for replying late i figured it out today

Answer (score 1):

From the description it really sounds like it would be better to use firestore instead of the cloud storage. However if you really need to read data from a excel file aka a csv you can use the [csv_reader package](https://pub.dev/packages/csv_reader).

```
var myCSV = CSV.from(url :'FILE_URL', delimiter: ",", title:true ); 
await myCSV.initFinished;

var rows = myCSV.rowCount;
var columns = myCSV.columnCount;
var cell = myCSV[row][column];
```

Comment: How will i use the numbers that exist in the excel file to sign in